# How do I capture the Chaos Kin in an electro trap?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

The treasure hunt says:

> Chapter 21: Capture the Chaos Kin 5 times with an electro trap.

How can I reliably train it into the trap? It's really skittish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did was I put the electro trap in between me and the Chaos kin. Every once in a while, it will rush at you, and doing so will trap it in an electro trap. If the battle lingers for a few minutes, Viridi will spawn more electro traps to trap him easier.

Comment: Argh, another case of me beating the boss too quickly. The extra traps helped a lot. Once they were out I found it best to stand in the middle of one; the Chaos Kin seemed to alternate between charging at me and getting stuck, and running away and getting stuck in the other one.